# How might the usable width and height of a tty terminal be set to less than the display dimensions?

Tags: terminal, size, tty

I have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to an LCD display and an e-ink display. Using [PaperTTY](https://github.com/joukos/PaperTTY), the e-ink display mirrors a portion of the tty terminal that is accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

The idea is that a text editor like [ne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_(text_editor)) can be run in the tty, mirrored on the e-ink display for typing in the sunlight. However, as the e-ink display shows only a portion of the terminal as it is shown on the LCD (say the top 40 % of rows displayed in the tty terminal), some way to artificially tell the tty terminal (or applications running within it) to be smaller is needed.

How might this be achieved?

The result might look like the tty terminal showing characters using only half the height of the LCD display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers of rows and columns used can be set using a command like the following:

```
stty cols 72 rows 25
```